# Json parsing using URLSession not working

Tags: ios, swift3, urlsession

Iam getting an error while i try to send the POST request in swift 3. Any one please suggest me the correct syntax for URLSession.shared method in swift 3. this is what i tried. iam new here.

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { 
            (data, response, error) in 

            if error != nil{
                print("error");
                return
            }

            do{
                let myjson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parsejson = myjson{
                    var msg: String!
                    msg = parsejson["message"] as! String?
                    print(msg)
                }catch error  {
                print ("")

                }
            }
            })
        task.resume().
```

Comment: you must use Alamofire, because it is effective and you should achieve it easily

Comment: @ohm Patel what have you tried , what have you searched? This can be simply googled.

Comment: Post the actual code you have from your app in a code block as part of the question, and describe in detail the error you get.

Comment: @DavidS. please check the uploaded code. any corrections and suggetions will be appreciated.

Comment: Change print("error") to print("error: \(error)") and see what the error is.  My guess if that line is firing is that you have the URL wrong or the server isn't running.

Comment: @DavidS. The error is in URLSession.shared line and the error says "ambigous reference to member 'dataTask(with: conpletionHandler:)" and anoter error is in "catch error " statement says " expected expression"

Comment: @DavidS.  Can you suggest me the changes i should make to my code

Answer (score 0):

Here's working URLSession.shared code.  I don't have your URL so I used one that is online, free, and produces JSON:

```
let someURL = URL(string:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2")!
let request = URLRequest(url: someURL)

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error")
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {
        print("No data")
        return
    }

    do {
        if let myjson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            if let title = myjson["title"] {
                print("Title was \"\(title)\"")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error parsing JSON: \(error)")
    }

}
task.resume()
```

This outputs `Title was "qui est esse"` for me.

Comment: Iam getting an error with this code. it says   ` Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void' `

Comment: iam getting an error mentioned above in comment. Do you have solution for this?

Comment: The code posted works perfectly in the latest Xcode.  Maybe you're using an old version.

Comment: Yes Iam using xcode 8. But I think it should work on this version as well.

Comment: Old Xcode, old Swift version.  Swift is an evolving language.  What version of Swift are you using in your project?

Comment: With Xcode 9 and Swift 3.2 this worked with zero code changes.  Not sure what you are doing wrong.  I can't re-install Xcode 8.

Comment: Ohkk ..Thank you so much for the help. It means a lot. Thank you once again.